# Добавление элемента к родительским на этапе его создания

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, relation, связи

Начал изучать Ruby On Rails, и при реализации примера столкнулся с таким вопросом.
Словесное описание структуры: есть врачи, есть пациенты, есть услуги. Нужно вести учет услуг (сеансов). Получается что у сеанса есть врач, пациент, услуга.
Создал модели врача, услуги, пациента. Встал вопрос модели сеанса. Получил такие связи:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :doctor
    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :service
end
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
end
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
..
  resources :patients do
    resources :appointments
  end
  resources :doctors do
    resources :appointments
  end
  resources :services do
    resources :appointments
  end
  resources :appointments
..
```

**appointment_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @appointment do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :doctor, "Доктор:"%>
        <%= select(:doctor, :doctor_id, Doctor.all.collect {|p| [ p.lastname, p.id ] }) %>
        <%= f.label :patient, "Пациент:"%>
        <%= select(:patient, :patient_id, Patient.all.collect {|p| [ p.lastname, p.id ] }) %>
        <%= f.label :service, "Услуга:"%>
        <%= select(:service, :service_id, Service.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>
        <%= f.label :date, "Дата оказания:" %><br>
        <%= f.date_select :date %>
        <%=f.submit ("Сохранить") %>
<% end %>
```

**appointments_controller.rb**

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @appointment = Appointment.new
    end
    def create
        @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient][:patient_id])
        @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:doctor][:doctor_id])
        @service = Service.find(params[:service][:service_id])
        @appointment = @patient.appointments.new(appointment_params)
        if @appointment.save
            redirect_to @appointment
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    private
        def appointment_params
            params.require(:appointment).permit(:date)
        end
end
```

---

**Вопрос:** как корректно добавить сеанс? Сейчас я в контроллере сеансов сначала определяю пациента, и уже от него добавляю сеанс, в итоге в сеансе заполнены только поля "пациент" и "дата". Как передать оставшиеся поля (врач, услуга)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `create` нужно реализовать добавление врача и услуги к новому сеансу:

```
def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient][:patient_id])
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:doctor][:doctor_id])
    @service = Service.find(params[:service][:service_id])
    @appointment = @patient.appointments.new(appointment_params)

    if @appointment.save
        success = false                            #+++
        @doctor.appointments << @appointment       #+++
        if @doctor.save then success = true        #+++

        @service.appointments << @appointment      #+++
        if @service.save and success then          #+++
            redirect_to @appointment
        else                                       #+++
            render 'new'                           #+++
        end                                        #+++
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```